# Why the window of my vb6 application stalls when calling a function written in C?

Tags: visual-c++, vb6

I'm using 3.9.7 cURL library to download files from the internet, so I created a dynamic bibioteca of viculo. dll written in C using VC + + 6.0 the problem is that when either I call my function from within my vb6 application window locks and unlocks only after you have downloaded the file how do I solve this problem?

Comment: vb6 doesnt have threading, not much you can do if the call to the DLL is taking a long time to execute.

Comment: Better to use something more sophisticated than a blocking-call based library like that one.  You can probably using something like VB6's built in AsyncRead method, the Internet Transfer Control ("Inet"), MSXML's XmlHttpRequest object, or Windows' own WinHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you call the function from your DLL, it "blocks" your app's execution until it gets finished. Basically, execution goes from the piece of code that makes the function call, to the code inside of the function call, and then only comes back to the next line after the function call after the code inside of the function has finished running. In fact, that's how all function calls work. You can see this for yourself by single-stepping through your code in the VB 6 development environment.

You don't normally notice this because the code inside of a function being called doesn't take very long to execute before control is returned to the caller. But in this case, since the function you're calling from the DLL is doing a lot of processing, it takes a while to execute, so it "blocks" the execution of your application's code for quite a while.

This is a good general explanation for the reason why your application window appears to be frozen. A bit more technically, it's because the message pump that is responsible for processing user interaction with on-screen elements is not running (it's part of your code that has been temporarily suspended until the function that you called finishes processing). This is a bit more difficult for a VB programmer to appreciate, since none of this nitty-gritty stuff is exposed in the world of VB. It's all happening behind the scenes, just like it is in a C program, but you don't normally have to deal with any of it. Occasionally, though, the abstraction leaks, and the nitty-gritty rears its ugly head. This is one of those cases.

The correct solution to this general problem, as others have hinted at, is to run lengthy operations on a background thread. This leaves your main thread (right now, the only one you have, the one your application is running on) free to continue processing user input, while the other thread can process the data and return that processed data to the main thread when it is finished. Of course, computers can't *actually* do more than one thing at a time, but the magic of the operating system rapidly switching between one task and another means that you can simulate this. The mechanism for doing so involves threads.

The catch comes in the fact that the VB 6 environment does not have any type of support for creating multiple threads. You only get one thread, and that's the main thread that your application runs on. If you freeze execution of that one, even temporarily, your application freezes—as you've already found out.

However, if you're already writing a C++ DLL, there's no reason you can't create multiple threads in a VB 6 app. You just have to handle everything yourself as if you were using another lower-level language like C++. Run the C++ code on a background thread, and only return its results to the main thread when it is completely finished. In the mean time, your main thread is free.

This is still quite a bit of work, though, especially if you're inexperienced when it comes to Win32 programming and the issues surrounding multiple threads. It might be easier to find a different library that supports asynchronous function calls out-of-the-box. [Antagony suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11658157/366904) using VB's [`AsyncRead` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277589.aspx). That is probably a good option; as Karl Peterson says in the linked article, it keeps everything in pure VB 6 code, which can be a real time saver as well as a boon to future maintenance programmers. The only problem is that you'll still have to *process* the data somehow once you obtain it. And if that's slow, you're right back where you started from…

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/03/27/simple-asynchronous-downloads.aspx), which demonstrates how to asynchronously transfer large files using a little-known method in user controls.